# Jellyfish tentacle animation using cloth modifier and force fields

Tags: cloth-simulation, force-fields

So I've been trying to get the first jellyfish's tentacles to move like the second jellyfish's tentacles.
I've figured out that the tentacles need to move in a helix-like spinning motion (basically the tentacles are rotating instead of making a back-and-forth motion).
The person who made the jellyfish on the right said they used a cloth modifier and force fields to get the jellyfish to move like that, but I'm not sure how exactly they did it.
If anyone has any input that would be super helpful[image]

here's the [second jellyfish](https://imgur.com/43Q5iIe)

[image]

Comment: Probably the created a vertex group of the jellyfishes body and used it as a pin group. You'd want some gradation in the vertex group so it doesn't go from pinned to not pinned instantly. 

Then they animated the body to bob up and down. Lastly they probably turned of gravity and added a turbulence force.

If you share your blender file it might be easier to get help.

Comment: @JamesSiewert - Here's [the model](https://blend-exchange.com/b/WmAwqSxz/) with all the cloth settings and some things I've tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a recepie other than you have ... it is more about try&error ... basically **Wind** force field with **Noise**, disabled **Gravity** (in my case) work somehow, but result is very fragile on mesh topology and cloth setup ... I'm not sure what to recommend ...

Here just a Wind in down direction ... (enabled **Falloff** > *Max Distance*)

[image]

Force Field object animated rotation at Z axis and under properties **Noise Amount** set to 10.

[image]

[image]

Probably the best - try to contact author (I saw his account on youtube or twitter), so try to catch him there).